# Use context var in struct member closure?

Tags: rust

I am not sure whether I am asking the right question. But I'll give it a shot:

I have a struct called Handlers:

```
pub struct Handlers {
    pub create: fn(u32) -> String,
}
```

Here the member named create is a closure when implemented.

So, why do I want to have a closure here?

Because on implemtation I want to use a variable from the context and I can only do that with a closure.

So, what I want to do, is this:

```
impl Handlers {
    fn new(name: &'static str) -> Self {
        Self {
            create: |id| {
                format!("create not implemented for name {} id {:}", name, id)
            },
        }
    }
}
```

When doing this I receive the error message

```
[rustc E0308] [E] mismatched types

expected fn pointer, found closure

note: expected fn pointer `fn(u32) -> std::string::String`
            found closure `[closure@src/handlers.rs:20:21: 25:14]`
```

The compiler infers a function pointer. And a function pointer is not what I need here. In order to capture the environment, it must infer a closure.

However, all is fine if I dont't use the variable "name" in the closure implementation. I.e. like this:

```
impl Handlers {
    fn new(name: &'static str) -> Self {
        Self {
            create: |id| {
                format!("create not implemented for id {:}", id)
            },
        }
    }
}
```

But I really need the variable "name" in my closure. Most likely I need to use somekind of a pointer solution, because the problem might have to do with scope.

I am still too much of a rookie to be able to wrap my head around a feasable solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing to understand is that `fn(u32) -> String` doesn't actually *represent* a closure. It simply represents a [function pointer](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.fn.html).

The second thing, is that while, e.g. `|x, y| x + y` is a [closure expression](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/closure-expr.html) it doesn't always result in a closure. If a closure expression doesn't capture an environment, then it can represent a ["plain function pointer"](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.fn.html#safety). This is why your second example works.

---

Instead you'll have to use any of the [`Fn`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Fn.html), [`FnMut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.FnMut.html), or [`FnOnce`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.FnOnce.html) traits. You'll additionally have to [`Box`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html) the closure.

```rust
pub struct Handlers {
    pub create: Box<dyn Fn(u32) -> String>,
}

impl Handlers {
    fn new(name: &'static str) -> Self {
        Self {
            create: Box::new(move |id| {
                format!("create not implemented for name {} id {:}", name, id)
            }),
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So, just to get an understanding in what your solution does: in other words, a pointer is being created for the closure and the closure is being put on the heap. 

How about "boxing" name? Would that also be an option?

Comment: @LongHike The main takeaway is that a closure is more than just a function pointer. Imagine you call `Handlers::new("foo")` and `Handlers::new("bar")`, then these "cannot" reuse the same closure, because the `name` value they use is different. In short, closures contain a pointer function along with all environment of all their variables, so to speak. Given that `Fn` is a trait and closures can be of any size, then this (the simplified reason of) why they need to be boxed.

Comment: You could also change `Handlers` to `struct Handlers<F: Fn(u32) -> String>` in which case the `Box` can be removed. However, that makes the `impl Handlers` a bit "annoying" if you want to attempt to call `Handlers::<...>::new()` as it would need to know the closure type.

Comment: Awesome explanation to all of my questions, thanks a lot!